# Curl PHP Error, how to fix?

Tags: php, api, curl

Im doing the following script: (Mojang Api)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json','Content-Type=application/json'

);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     '{
    "agent": {                              
        "name": "Minecraft",                
        "version": 1                        

    },
    "username": "idk",      

    "password": "something",
    "requestUser": true                     
}' ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/plain')); 

$result=curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Its giving this answer:

```
{"error":"Unsupported Media Type","errorMessage":"The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method"}
```

How to fix the error of unsupported media type?

Comment: I tried it with postman and postman is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a cow.

This line of code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/plain'));
```

Tells that its plain text

But it needs to be this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```